# Very slow connection to xserve via afp or smb

Tags: afp

Help. File transfer and connection speed to our Xserve are painfully slow from newly purchased iMacs. The Xserve is only used as a file server, its running 10.4.11. The problem seems to be only happening on brand new iMacs running 10.6.3. When connected either over afp or smb copying files is many times slower than usual. Other machines on the network running either 10.4 or 10.5 have a normal connection speed. To try to rule out OS incompatibility I connected the new iMac running 10.6 to another computer running 10.4 over the network. The file transfer speed was fast as normal. So it seems the problems lies with the X serve (maybe). The afp logs either access or error don't show anything unusual. One thing that did look different was when the imac was connected to the Xserve the user had its id listed as its IP address. The other machines connected, had the id of broadcasthost. I also noticed that when connected from the new iMac I can only see one of the mirrors. When any other computer connects both mirrors are shown. Tried a restart of the Xserve but the problem persists.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Have you tried this? 
http://serverfault.com/questions/126120/afp-painfully-slow

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is do a trace route from the new clients to the problem Xserve. If that looks normal, try mounting the share on the xserver using ciffs:// instead of afp:// or smb://.

You could also attempt to force your new Macs to run at 100mbps/duplex. If the network connection was flakey it could be doing odd things to transfers.